# How to check if PATH already contains a particular directory

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I want to be able to reload a users .profile so that it "permanently" updates the PATH without having to restart the system. This is what I'm doing within the .profile file and it's not working.

```
if [[$PATH != "*path_to_directory*"]];then
     PATH=<path_to_directory>:$PATH
fi
```

After I save that addition to the .profile, i run source .profile to reload it, but I just get an error and my PATH isn't updated.

Comment: And what error do you get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 problems with your statement. First, you need to add a space after `[[` and before `]]`. Second, the `*` should be outside the quotes for it to match string:

```
if [[ $PATH != *"path_to_directory"* ]];then
    echo "adding path to directory"
    PATH=path_to_directory:$PATH
fi
```

So the output of will be:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
$ source .profile
adding path to directory
$ echo $PATH
path_to_directory:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
$ source .profile
$ echo $PATH
path_to_directory:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

Comment: I'm new to scripting, I didn't realize the spaces actually matter!

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu comes with a handy utility function called `pathmunge`.  This utility does exactly what you're trying to do... it adds a directory to your path unless it already exists.

Here's a duplicate version I wrote for OSX (but should work on most *nix systems)

```
function pathmunge() {
    if [ "$2" = "force" ] || ! echo $PATH | $(which egrep) -q "(^|:)$1($|:)" ; then
        if [ "$2" = "after" ] ; then
            PATH=$PATH:$1
        else
            PATH=$1:$PATH
        fi
        export PATH
    fi
}
```

This is how you use it:

```
# Modify the path
pathmunge /usr/local/bin        force
pathmunge /usr/local/sbin       force
pathmunge $HOME/.rbenv/bin
pathmunge /usr/local/heroku/bin
pathmunge $HOME/bin             after
```